# Prove that $\frac{(n-2)s^2}{\sigma^2}\sim \chi^{2}_{n-2}$

Tags: regression, probability, distributions

Consider the following simple linear regression model involving the $\epsilon_i$ error term,

$$y_i = \alpha + \beta x_i + \epsilon_i$$

such that,

$$\epsilon_i \sim \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$$

we know that if $Z_1, Z_2, ..., Z_n$ are independent, standard normal random variables,

$$Z_i \sim \mathcal N(0,1)$$

then the sum of their squares is distributed according to the chi-square distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom,

$$\sum _{i=1}^{n} Z_{i}^{2} \sim \chi^{2}_{n}$$

Now let's prove that $\frac{(n-2)s^2}{\sigma^2}\sim \chi^{2}_{n-2}$ such that,

$$s^2 = \frac{\sum _{i=1}^{n} \hat{\epsilon}_i^2}{n-2}$$

**Proof:**

$\require{cancel}$

$$\epsilon_i \sim \mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$$

$$\frac{\epsilon_i - \cancelto{0}{\overline{\epsilon}}}{\sigma} \sim \mathcal N(0, 1)$$

$$\sum _{i=1}^{n} \left(\frac{\epsilon_i}{\sigma}\right)^2 \sim \chi^{2}_{n}$$

$$\sum _{i=1}^{n} \frac{\epsilon_i^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi^{2}_{n}$$

How do I now move from this expression $\sum _{i=1}^{n} \frac{\epsilon_i^2}{\sigma^2}$ which uses the error term $\epsilon_i$ to this expression $\sum _{i=1}^{n} \frac{\hat{\epsilon}_i^2}{\sigma^2}$ which uses the residual term $\hat{\epsilon}_i$?

**Note:**

I came across this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/362590/simple-linear-regression-how-does-sigma-hatu-i2-sigma2-follow-chi-squar) but I got lost in the second part of the demonstration and I wanted to know if there is a simpler method that would lead to the same answer.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20227/why-is-rss-distributed-chi-square-times-n-p?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I think you need to assume the residuals are independent, though I have no idea how to go about showing they are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without using the orthogonal change of variables in the linked answer, you can work under the general matrix setup of multiple linear regression. Here we are concerned with [ordinary least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares).

The key result to be used here is the Fisher-Cochran theorem on distribution of quadratic forms (e.g. see page 185-186, 2nd edition of [*Linear Statistical Inference and Its Applications*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471218758) by Rao).

Suppose the model is $$y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1x_i+\varepsilon_i$$

Define the vectors $y=(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$, $\beta=(\beta_0,\beta_1)$ and $\varepsilon=(\varepsilon_1,\ldots,\varepsilon_n)$.

> So in matrix form you have $$y=X\beta+\varepsilon\,,$$ where $X_{n\times k}$ with rank $k$ (here $k=2$) is the matrix of covariates (fixed) and $\varepsilon\sim N(0,\sigma^2 I_n)$.

By standard algebra of least squares, $$\hat y=X\hat\beta=X(X'X)^{-1}X'y=Hy\,,$$ where $H=X(X'X)^{-1}X'$ is the hat matrix. Note that $H$ is symmetric and idempotent.

The residual vector is

\begin{align}
e=y-\hat y&=(I_n-H)y
\\&=(I_n-H)(X\beta+\varepsilon)
\\&=(I_n-H)\varepsilon
\end{align}

Now $I_n-H$ is symmetric and idempotent because $H$ is so.

So the residual sum of squares is

\begin{align}
e'e&=y'(I_n-H)'(I_n-H)y
\\&=y'(I_n-H)y 
\\&=\varepsilon'(I_n-H)\varepsilon
\end{align}

Therefore $$\frac{(n-2)s^2}{\sigma^2}=\frac{e'e}{\sigma^2}=\left(\frac{\varepsilon}{\sigma}\right)'(I_n-H)\frac{\varepsilon}{\sigma}$$

By a corollary of the Fisher-Cochran theorem, the above has a chi-square distribution because $(I_n-H)$ is idempotent, the degrees of freedom being $\operatorname{rank}(I_n-H)$.

As rank of an idempotent matrix equals its trace, $\operatorname{rank}(I_n-H)=\operatorname{tr}(I_n-H)=n-\operatorname{tr}(H)$.

And by properties of trace, $\operatorname{tr}(H)=\operatorname{tr}(X(X'X)^{-1}X')=\operatorname{tr}(X'X(X'X)^{-1})=\operatorname{tr}(I_k)=k$

Comment: Hi @StubbornAtom, if you don't mind, in the residual vector step why is $(I_n-H)(X\beta+\varepsilon)=(I_n-H)\varepsilon$? How is $(X\beta+\varepsilon)=\varepsilon$? Thanks in adavnce.

Comment: Sure.  $X\beta+\varepsilon=\varepsilon$ is obviously *not* true. You have $HX=X$ and

\begin{align}
(I_n-H)(X\beta+\varepsilon)&=(I_n-H)X\beta+(I_n-H)\varepsilon
\\&=X\beta-HX\beta+(I_n-H)\varepsilon 
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you so much @StubbornAtom.

Comment: The theorem specifically used is a special case of the one here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/188626/119261.